# Reversing Lists Splices Python Optimization (USACO February 2020 Bronze Question 3 "Swapity Swap")

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, simulation, reverse

I am trying to solve a problem that involves reversing list splices, and I am having trouble with the time limit for a test case,, which is 4 seconds. The question:

Farmer John's N cows (1≤N≤100) are standing in a line. The ith cow from the left has label i, for each 1≤i≤N.
Farmer John has come up with a new morning exercise routine for the cows. He tells them to repeat the following two-step process exactly K (1≤K≤1000000000) times:

The sequence of cows currently in positions A1…A2 from the left reverse their order (1≤A1<A2≤N).
Then, the sequence of cows currently in positions B1…B2 from the left reverse their order (1≤B1<B2≤N).
After the cows have repeated this process exactly K times, please output the label of the ith cow from the left for each 1≤i≤N.

**SCORING**:
Test cases 2-3 satisfy K≤100.
Test cases 4-13 satisfy no additional constraints.

**INPUT FORMAT** (file swap.in):
The first line of input contains N and K. The second line contains A1 and A2, and the third contains B1 and B2.

**OUTPUT FORMAT** (file swap.out):
On the ith line of output, print the label of the ith cow from the left at the end of the exercise routine.

**SAMPLE INPUT**:

```
7 2
2 5
3 7
```

**SAMPLE OUTPUT**:

```
1
2
4
3
5
7
6
```

Initially, the order of the cows is [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] from left to right. After the first step of the process, the order is [1,5,4,3,2,6,7]. After the second step of the process, the order is [1,5,7,6,2,3,4]. Repeating both steps a second time yields the output of the sample.

Theoretically, you could solve this problem by finding the point where the program repeats, and then simulating the reverse `k % frequency` times, where `frequency` is the amount of times the simulation is unique.
But my problem is that when the input is:

```
100 1000000000
1 94
2 98
```

my program takes over 100 seconds to run. This input is particularly time consuming because it runs the maximum number of iterations, and `frequency` is very high.

Current Code:

```
fin = open("swap.in", 'r')
line = fin.readline().strip().split()
n = int(line[0])
k = int(line[1])
nums = [[int(x)-1 for x in fin.readline().strip().split()]for i in range(2)]
fin.close()
repeated = []
cows = [i for i in range(1, n+1)]
repeat = False
while not repeat:
    for i in nums:
        cows[i[0]:i[1]+1] = reversed(cows[i[0]:i[1]+1])
        if cows[i[0]:i[1]+1] in repeated :
            frequency = len(repeated)-1
            repeat = True
        repeated.append(cows[i[0]:i[1]+1])

cows = [i for i in range(1, n+1)]
for _ in range(k%frequency):
    for i in nums:
        cows[i[0]:i[1]+1] = reversed(cows[i[0]:i[1]+1])

fout = open("swap.out", 'w')
for i in cows:
    fout.write(str(i) + "\n")
fout.close()
```

If anyone knows a way to solve this issue, please post an answer. Comment if anything isn't clear.

Comment: I re-read the code and see how you're attempting to implement the cycle detection. Are you expecting the `for i in nums` loop to exit as soon as `repeat` gets set to `True`, because of the *outer* `while not repeat:` loop? Loops don't work that way. The `while not repeat:` condition will only be checked once per iteration of *that* loop, implying a *complete run* of the inner loop.

Comment: If you're doing contest problems and trying to think about algorithms carefully, I assume you don't need to be told about fundamentals like `break`. So I assume this was just a simple oversight caused by the pressure of competition.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel No, I intentionally didn't put in a break. If you did put in a break and changed frequency = `len(repeated)-1` to `frequency = len(repeated)`, it doesn't work when you try it with the input case 
    `100 31279131
    1 100
    2 99`
 I am also not currently in a competition, this is just a practice problem.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Do you have any idea how I could solve this?

Comment: I see, `for i in nums` is iterating over the two (hard-coded) swaps being done. That's a little awkward. I think the problem is that as the period of the cycle (what you call `frequency` in your code) increases, it takes O(n^2) work to search for a cycle (using `in repeated` O(n) times, while that operation is itself O(n)). However, I think you can prove that the cycle will only ever repeat by resetting the initial position.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Sorry, I don't really comprehend what you mean by "you can prove that the cycle will only ever repeat by resetting the initial position." Could you elaborate?

Comment: "He tells them to repeat the following two-step process exactly K (1≤K≤109) times". So why K = 1000000000 in that test case?

Comment: @blhsing Sorry, that should be exponent. 10 to the ninth.

Comment: @user3386109 It's inside. That's what is making the time complexity O(n^2). I just don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lets first talk about how we could solve this mathematically, and then work out a solution programmatically.

Lets say the cow at each position is represented by the variable `Pi.j`,  where `i` is the cow index, and `j` is the the swap iteration. These variables will each contain an integer corresponding to that cow's unique id. Also, for simplicity, we'll only consider a single reversal operation per iteration, and expand to include both later on.

Starting with P0.0 (0th position, 0th iteration), we want to start defining some equations to give us the cow at a given position on the next iteration. If the cow is outside of the reversal region, this is trivial; the cow does not change. If it is within the reversal region, we'll want to calculate the previous position of the new cow based on the endpoints of the reversal region. Explicitly:

- if outside reversal region: `Pi.(j+1) = Pi.j`
- else: `Pi.(j+1) = P(e1+e2-i).j`, where `e1` and `e2` are the region endpoints

Now, with our rules, we can actually write out a system of equations:

```
P0.b = 1 * P0.a
P1.b = 1 * P1.a
...
P4.b = 1 * P7.a  // reversal region starts
P5.b = 1 * P6.a
...
```

From here, we can transform these system of questions to a transformation matrix `MA`, which when multiplied by a vector of cow ids, will return a new vector of cow ids post-reversal.

This is where things get fancy. We can do the same thing for the other reversal region, making a second matrix `MB`, and multiply it with `MA` to get an overall matrix `M` which does both reversals in one. From here, we can raise the matrix to the power `K` (the number of iterations), for a single matrix which will calculate the cows at each position after all reversals take place.

Now, at this point, you're probably questioning the performance of this approach- afterall, we're raising a 100x100 matrix to some power `K` up to `109`! Well, we've got a few tricks up our sleeves to make this much faster. First, note that a single cow, any cow, we can logically reason through shuffling across all the reversal operations and determine its end position, all without knowing anything about where the other cows are / which other cows are which.

This means for any given position at any given time, the cow at that position can be defined by exactly one other position on any other iteration (e.g. P12.7 (position 12 iteration 7) can determined exactly by knowing the cow at the corresponding position in iteration, say, iteration 5-  P8.5).

This is useful because it means each row of our matrix will have exactly one non-zero element, and that element will have a value of `1` (coefficient of `1` in the system of equations) so we can actually compress our our 100x100 matrix into an array of just 100 values stating which column per row holds the `1`.

Great, we can trivially multiply matrices in `O(n^2)` time using this trick. Well, we can actually do a bit better yet- we can actually multiply these in `O(n)` time. For each "row" `R` (containing just the column index, `I` of the `1` value) in the first matrix, look at the `I`th row in our second matrix, and get its value `C`. Assign our corresponding row `R'` in the output matrix to equal `C`.

So we can multiply these matrices in ~100 logical steps, but we need raise this matrix to the `K`th power, which could be up to `109`. We just eliminated a factor of 100 from our work, just to add it right back! Well, not quite. There's a well-known method for matrix exponentiation called "exponentiation by squaring", where we cleverly stagger multiplying and squaring the result repeatedly, to calculate `M^K` in `log(K)` iterations/steps. I won't go into detail here since its widely known and well-documented.

Overall, that puts us at O(N log K) time, not too bad!

**Update**: Here is the functioning code to solve the problem.

```py
def matmul(p, q):
    return [q[I] for I in p]

def exp(m, e):
    if e == 1:
        return m

    result = exp(matmul(m, m), e // 2)
    if e % 2:
        result = matmul(m, result)
    return result

def solve(n, k, a1, a2, b1, b2):
    a1, a2, b1, b2 = a1-1, a2-1, b1-1, b2-1

    cows = list(range(1, n+1))

    ma = [a1 + a2 - x if a1 <= x <= a2 else x for x in range(n)]
    mb = [b1 + b2 - x if b1 <= x <= b2 else x for x in range(n)]

    m0 = matmul(mb, ma)
    mk = exp(m0, k)

    return [cows[i] for i in mk]
```

After doing some benchmarks using `timeit` for `number=100` iterations, these were my findings (timings in seconds, smaller is better):

```
contributor      | time (sec)
------------------------------
blhsing          | 7.857691
Michael Szczesny | 5.076418
(mine)           | 0.013314
```

So Michael's improves on blhsing's solution by running about 1.5x faster on my machine, and my solution runs about 381x faster than Michael's, taking roughly a ten-thousandth of a second per run on average.

**Update 2**: As mentioned in the comment of this answer, the above solution does still scale with `K`, so eventually it would become intractable, and this problem seems to emit a repetitive pattern- surely we can exploit that? Well, yes, in fact we can.

The trick is that there's only so many ways we can permute these cows before they reach some previous state that we've seen before, and then form an endless cycle from there. In fact- because of the simplicity of the problem at hand, its typically a relatively small number of shuffles / reversals before we arrive back at a previous state (actually our *starting* state specifically, since to visit any other cow permutation without first visiting our starting state would imply that there's two distinct states that transition to said state, which cannot be-  we have our system of equations which told us otherwise).

So, what we need to do if find this magic number where the cow shuffling / reversals starts repeating, and use that to reduce the exponent (in our matrix exponentiation) from `K` to `K mod MAGIC`. We're actually going to call this number the multiplicative order of the transition matrix. To start, notice that there may be more than one cycle of cows that shuffle positions, each of which repeats with periods. A subset of 4 cows may cycle positions every 4 iterations, while another subset of 3 cows cycles every 3 iterations, meaning together the 7 cows repeat their starting configuration every 12 iterations.

More generally, we need to find each independent cycle of cow shuffles, get their lengths, and find the least common multiple (LCM) of these periods. Once we have that, take `K` mod that, and raise our matrix to that *new* value. Example code for doing so:

```py
from itertools import count
from functools import reduce
from math import lcm

def order(m):
    cycle_lens = []
    unvisited = set(m)

    while unvisited:
        start = head = unvisited.pop()
        for size in count(1):
            head = m[head]
            if head == start:
                cycle_lens.append(size)
                break
            unvisited.discard(head)

    return reduce(lcm, cycle_lens)

# And inside solve()-
# replace:   mk = exp(m0, k)
# with:      mk = exp(m0, k % order(m0))
```

Comment: Amazing math, well explained. Thanks. +1. I do wonder if there's a more mathematical approach in solving the "frequency" that the OP and I are trying to find, since with your current approach there's no cap to the time cost so if there's no limit to `k` theoretically this approach would at some point cost more time than finding the frequency first and spending no more than "one cycle" of time regardless of the magnitude of `k`.

Comment: @blhsing I do actually have a trick up my sleeves to cap it off to be `O(n)`, independent of `K`, but for the problem size at hand, the extra work actually doesn't provide a meaningful speedup. I'll expand my answer to include it for completeness-  maybe someone else can find a way to compute the order without explicit looping, providing a further speedup.

Comment: Thank you! Really well explained!

Comment: Does the order calculation take into account that individual elements can have multiple repeated locations within any one cycle?

Comment: @DillonDavis in https://stackoverflow.com/a/69004463/585411 I showed how to make it `O(N)`.  I believe that if you code it up, it will be faster.

Comment: @גלעדברקן yes, because `m` represents one full iteration through all intermediate steps / reversals, so its impossible to "stop" inbetween, say between reversals A and B.

Comment: @btilly that's clever-  you seem to be doing something conceptually similar, but rather than combining the cycles for one large period, you compute the values for each cycle independently, for a potentially smaller exponent.

Comment: Update two is a nice speedup, but unfortunately, the USACO website only runs on Python 3.6, while `math.lcm` was added after that.

Comment: @CoderTang `lcm` can be defined with: `def lcm(a, b): return a * b // gcd(a, b)`

Answer (score 4):

Here is an approach that is `O(N)` work no matter what `K` might be.

Condensed explanation:  Rewrite the permutation in cycle notation.  Use cycle notation to generate the answer.  (Except we don't need the full cycle notation.

To illustrate I'll use your example, but I'll find the permutation after 999 steps.

As you note, `[1,5,7,6,2,3,4]` is the result one iteration of A then B.  Calculating that, in this form, clearly takes `O(N)` work.  It is a little more convenient to write that as:

```
{
    1: 1,
    2: 5,
    3: 6,
    4: 7,
    5: 2,
    6: 4,
    7: 3
}
```

Again, this translation takes `O(N)` work.

Now let's compute a partial answer.  We start with `[0,0,0,0,0,0,0]' where` 0` means "unknown".

First step, we find `1 -> 1` so the first cycle is just `(1)`.  Going around this cycle 999 times gives us `(1)` again, so we now have `[1,0,0,0,0,0,0]`.

Second step, we find that `2 -> 5 -> 2` (note, we're just looking these up in the lookup, so each one is `O(1)` work) so the second cycle is `(2, 5)`.  Going around this cycle 999 steps means we get to fill in 2 values.  We now have `[1,5,0,0,2,0,0]`.

Third step, we find that `3 -> 6 -> 4 -> 7 -> 3`.  So the third cycle is `(3, 6, 4, 7)`.  Going around this 999 times is like walking 3 steps forward, so now we can fill in: `[1,5,7,6,2,3,4]`.

As we go through the rest of the numbers, we find that they are all filled in.  So our answer is `[1,5,7,6,2,3,4]`.

In general, each number is part of a cycle of length `j`.  When we find a cycle, we take `O(j)` work to find the cycle, and then for another `O(j)` work we fill in the answer of what happens to that cycle.  Afterwards we will hit `j-1` elements that are filled in and skip them.  So we get `n` elements for `O(n)` work, for amortized `O(1)` work per element.

The result is `O(N)` work to find the final answer.

Comment: So you just sort each number individually?

Comment: I'm not sure if you meant to imply this in your description but the cycles aren't "regular" permutation cycles. For example, the example in the description has 2 -> 5 -> 5 (stays since its the middle of B) -> 2 -> 2 (stays because B doesn't affect 2), etc.

Comment: @גלעדברקן A and B are both permutations.  Therefore BA (do A then do B) is a permutation.  We are doing `K` iterations of THAT permutation.  And because A and B always happen together, we don't have any reason to care about the intermediate state when A has happened but B has not yet.

Therefore we are talking a real permutation with regular permutation cycles.

Comment: @CoderTang Yes.  But when you do the number, you fill in its whole cycle.

Comment: I'm used to thinking of a permutation as a singular mapping from one index to another, where cycles only include one of each index. I appreciate the opportunity to extend that concept.

Comment: Ha, I also missed that each step of k means running both A and B :)

Comment: I tested your approach and added code and a benchmark to my answer.

Comment: Very clever indeed. +1 I did not notice that there are several cycles within the overall big cycle, whose magical "frequency" is simply the least common multiple of the sizes of all individual cycles. I've implemented your solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69007619/6890912). Timing of the 3 implementations of your algorithm as well as the solution of @DillonDavis can be found here: https://replit.com/@blhsing/EquatorialRemorsefulMath

Comment: @blhsing and a more optimised version of the third here: https://replit.com/@gl_dbrqn/EquatorialRemorsefulMath :) btilly, is there a way to simplify the two mathematical assignments of j to one?

Answer (score 3):

The main problem with the performance of your code is that you're using a list to keep a history of cow positions in each iteration in order to detect a cycle, which requires *O(n)* for each membership lookup with the `in` operator.

Instead, you can use a set for the purpose, which costs *O(1)* in membership lookups. But since you still need to then iterate *k % i* times, where *i* is the length of the cycle, to get to that specific position in the cycle, it would be better if the set is ordered so you can simply get the *(k % i)*-indexed entry in the set instead of having to perform that many times of reversals. But since set is unordered in Python, you can instead use a dict, where the keys are ordered since Python 3.6:

```
from itertools import islice

n, k, a1, a2, b1, b2 = map(int, '''100 1000000000
1 94
2 98'''.split())
cows = list(range(1, n + 1))
history = {}
for i in range(k):
    key = tuple(cows)
    if key in history:
        cows = next(islice(history, k % i, None))
        break
    history[key] = 1
    for bound in map(slice, (a1 - 1, b1 - 1), (a2, b2)):
        cows[bound] = reversed(cows[bound])
print(*cows, sep='\n')
```

This outputs:

```
71
2
3
74
10
76
7
8
79
15
81
12
13
84
20
86
17
18
89
25
91
22
23
94
30
96
27
28
1
35
4
32
33
6
40
9
37
38
11
45
14
42
43
16
50
19
47
48
21
55
24
52
53
26
60
29
57
58
31
65
34
62
63
36
70
39
67
68
41
75
44
72
73
46
80
49
77
78
51
85
54
82
83
56
90
59
87
88
61
95
64
92
93
66
5
69
97
98
99
100
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/CultivatedPointedArchitect

Answer (score 3):

You can get rid of the look up. This computes the necessary 5680 swaps twice, but saves the extra space for the dictionary. On a google colab instance this solution runs 33% faster than [@blhsing solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68993307/14277722) for this particular example.

```
n, k, a1, a2, b1, b2 = [int(x) for x in
    '''
    100 1000000000
    1 94
    2 98
    '''.split()]
a1 -= 1
b1 -= 1

cows = list(range(1, n+1))
rot = cows[:]
s = k

while k:
    rot[a1:a2] = reversed(rot[a1:a2])
    rot[b1:b2] = reversed(rot[b1:b2])
    k -= 1
    if rot == cows:
        print(f'found frequency {s-k}')
        k %= s-k

print(*rot)
```

Output

```
found frequency 29640
71 2 3 74 10 76 7 8 79 15 81 12 13 84 20 86 17 18 89 25 91 22 23 94 30 96 27 28 1 35 4 32 33 6 40 9 37 38 11 45 14 42 43 16 50 19 47 48 21 55 24 52 53 26 60 29 57 58 31 65 34 62 63 36 70 39 67 68 41 75 44 72 73 46 80 49 77 78 51 85 54 82 83 56 90 59 87 88 61 95 64 92 93 66 5 69 97 98 99 100
```

---

### [@btilly's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69004463/14277722)

I coded his approach and got 4x faster runtime to @dillondavis' first solution (320 µs / 78.9 µs)

```
n, k, a1, a2, b1, b2 = [int(x) for x in
    '''
    100 1000000000
    1 94
    2 98
    '''.split()]
a1 -= 1
b1 -= 1
cows = list(range(n))
cows[a1:a2] = reversed(cows[a1:a2])
cows[b1:b2] = reversed(cows[b1:b2])

visited = set()
runs = []
for i in cows:
    if i not in visited:
        run = [i]
        nex = cows[i]
        while nex != i:
            run.append(nex)
            nex = cows[nex]
            visited.add(nex)
        runs.append(run)
for i in runs:
    r = k % len(i)
    for x,y in zip(i, i[r:]+i[:r]):
        cows[x] = y+1
print(*cows)
```

Output

```
71 2 3 74 10 76 7 8 79 15 81 12 13 84 20 86 17 18 89 25 91 22 23 94 30 96 27 28 1 35 4 32 33 6 40 9 37 38 11 45 14 42 43 16 50 19 47 48 21 55 24 52 53 26 60 29 57 58 31 65 34 62 63 36 70 39 67 68 41 75 44 72 73 46 80 49 77 78 51 85 54 82 83 56 90 59 87 88 61 95 64 92 93 66 5 69 97 98 99 100
```

Comment: Good point. It's going to always cycle to the original position first before repeating others so there's no point in looking for anything else other than the original position. +1

Comment: Simplest Logic. Very easy to comprehend! Thanks!

Comment: Ah, beat me to it :-). But can still make it about 4 times faster by using `bytearray` and `[::-1]` instead of `list` and `reversed`. And @blhsing could similarly make theirs about 3-4 times faster (with additionally using `bytes` instead of `tuple`).

Answer (score 1):

Another implementation of [@btilly's algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69004463/6890912) with my understanding, written before I realized @MichaelSzczesny has posted his:

```
n, k, a1, a2, b1, b2 = map(int, '''100 1000000000
1 94
2 98'''.split())
*positions, = *mapped, = range(n)
for bound in map(slice, (a1 - 1, b1 - 1), (a2, b2)):
    mapped[bound] = reversed(mapped[bound])
mapping = dict(zip(mapped, positions))
cycles = []
pool = set(positions)
while pool:
    current = pool.pop()
    cycle = [current]
    while True:
        current = mapping[current]
        if current == cycle[0]:
            break
        pool.remove(current)
        cycle.append(current)
    cycles.append(cycle)
result = [0] * n
for cycle in cycles:
    for i, position in enumerate(cycle):
        result[cycle[(k + i) % len(cycle)]] = position + 1
print(*result)
```

This outputs:

```
71 2 3 74 10 76 7 8 79 15 81 12 13 84 20 86 17 18 89 25 91 22 23 94 30 96 27 28 1 35 4 32 33 6 40 9 37 38 11 45 14 42 43 16 50 19 47 48 21 55 24 52 53 26 60 29 57 58 31 65 34 62 63 36 70 39 67 68 41 75 44 72 73 46 80 49 77 78 51 85 54 82 83 56 90 59 87 88 61 95 64 92 93 66 5 69 97 98 99 100
```

Timing statistics show that this is somewhat faster than @MichaelSzczesny's implementation:
https://replit.com/@blhsing/EquatorialRemorsefulMath

Comment: My implementation computes additionally: N times adding to the visited `set` and N times checking if the current cow is already in the `set` while extracting the cycles. Removing used items from `pool` set saves 2*N work. Otherwise very similar implementations.

Comment: And maybe it is faster to compute N times modulo than computing modulo once and constructing a shifted list (needs 3 new lists) for each cycle.

Comment: Indeed. Very subtle differences in approaches to implementing @btilly 's algorithm and very marginally different performance. The construction of the 3 new lists for each cycle could be avoided with `itertools.islice` and `itertools.chain` though.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another version of what I understand as [btilly's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69004463/2034787) cycle approach. Working Python code submitted to [USACO](http://usaco.org/index.php?page=viewproblem2&cpid=1013):

```py
import collections

def f(n, k, ai, aj, bi, bj):
  # A cycle necessarily has even parity as both A and B
  # must be run. We know a cycle is complete when the
  # element returns to the start and the parity is even.
  cycles = collections.defaultdict(list)

  # Get cycles
  for i in range(1, n + 1):
    j = i
    parity = 0
    first_cycle = 1

    while first_cycle or j != i or parity:
      # A
      if not parity:
        j = j if (j < ai or j > aj) else aj - j + ai
      # B
      else:
        j = j if (j < bi or j > bj) else bj - j + bi
        first_cycle = 0

      if parity: 
        cycles[i].append(j)

      parity ^= 1

  new_list = [None] * n

  for i in range(1, n + 1):
    idx = cycles[i][(k - 1) % len(cycles[i])]
    new_list[idx-1] = str(i)

  file = open("swap.out", "w")
  file.write("\n".join(new_list))
  file.close()


file = open("swap.in","r")
data = file.readlines()

[n, k] = map(int, data[0].split())
[ai, aj] = map(int, data[1].split())
[bi, bj] = map(int, data[2].split())
  
f(n, k, ai, aj, bi, bj)


"""
ai = 2
aj = 5
bi = 3
bj = 7

n = 7
k = 2
"""

"""
1
2
4
3
5
7
6
"""
```

[image]

Comment: When you set `ai = 1` `aj = 94` `bi = 2` `bj = 98` `n = 100` `k = 1000`, it outputs the wrong answer.

Comment: There's something incredibly inefficient with your implementation, as it is more than 30 times slower than @MichaelSzczesny's and my implementation of btilly's algorithm. Timing demo can be found here: https://replit.com/@blhsing/EquatorialRemorsefulMath

Comment: @blhsing cool, thanks for testing it. Right, it calculates and records the cycle for each element separately, rather than just recording the cycles per se.

Comment: @blhsing now it's better optimised. Here: https://replit.com/@gl_dbrqn/EquatorialRemorsefulMath

Comment: @blhsing DillonDavis 0.4136610489949817; 
blhsing (tbilly) 0.20110821699927328; 
MichaelSzczesny (tbilly) 0.22961177600518567; 
גלעד ברקן (tbilly) 0.19056547000218416